# Jquery z-index, Strange behaviour on trigger buttons

Tags: jquery, onclick, z-index, css-animations

I don't know how to ask this question but i'll start with my code.
here is the HTML and js

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="behind-bg"></div>
            <div id="code" class="code">

                <a id="testlink" href="#">Click Here</a><br>
                <a id="testlink" href="#">Click Here</a><br>
                <a id="testlink" href="#">Click Here</a>


            </div>
                <div id="curl" class="curl"></div>
            <div id="check-box-float">



            <div id="open" class="toggle-menu">
            <div id="close" class="toggle-menu">
            </div>


        </body>

        <script>
            $(function() { 
                $("#open").click(function() { 
                    $(".curl").toggleClass("curl-out"); 
                }); 
            }); 

            $(function() { 
                $("#open").click(function() { 
                    $(".code").toggleClass("menu-reveal"); 
                }); 
            }); 

            $(function() { 
                $("#close").click(function() { 
                    $(".code").toggleClass("menu-unreveal"); 
                }); 
            }); 
        </script>


    </html>
```

and here is the css t go with it.

```
#open {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background: black;
    top: 200px;
    left: 400px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#close {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -9;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 40px;
}

.curl{
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0) 48%, rgba(229,229,229,0.75) 51%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 52%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(48%,rgba(112,112,112,0)), color-stop(51%,rgba(229,229,229,0.75)), color-stop(52%,rgba(229,229,229,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(249,249,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0) 48%,rgba(229,229,229,0.75) 51%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 52%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0) 48%,rgba(229,229,229,0.75) 51%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 52%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(112,112,112,0) 48%,rgba(229,229,229,0.75) 51%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 52%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(112,112,112,0) 48%,rgba(229,229,229,0.75) 51%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 52%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */

    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #d3d3d3;
    z-index: 20;
    transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease; 
}


.curl-out { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #d3d3d3;
} 

.code{
    background:#fffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 10;

}

.menu-reveal { 
    transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease, z-index 3s ease;
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px;
    z-index: 50;
} 

.menu-unreveal {
    transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease, z-index 0s ease;
    width: 15px; 
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The problem I am getting is the behaviour of the two buttons (THE BLACK AND YELLOW BOXES)

when you load the page and click the black box the page curls and the text reveals with an ease - thats what i want. However, when you click the black button again the text doesn't disappear with an ease it just disappears.

next

if you refresh your browser and click the yellow button first the page curls but the the text does not reveal - that's fine too -- it's not programmed too. the black box has the #open ID

the problem is this - hit refresh again now click the black button first. this will open the curl and reveal the text, then if you keep clicking the yellow box it will work as desired ease in and out revealing the text with a z-index that makes it clickable too.

**WHAT I WANT** I want one button that works from the start which eases in and eases out. However, when the curl "closes" i want the z-index to animate immediately (so there is no delay when the page curl closes.)

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Create jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ to work with.

Comment: Just a question, whats the problem with just using the animation that comes from the yellow button? It hides and shows the menu nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to get the transition added to an element BEFORE you make any changes. I've setup a fiddle to illustrate this and I think it achieves your goal:
http://jsfiddle.net/xV9Rx/

**Essentially:**

1. I've removed the yellow button since it isn't needed.
2. I've moved `transition` properties around like so:

   .code {
       transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease, z-index 0s ease; /* no delay on z-index */
   }

   .menu-reveal { 
       transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease, z-index 3s ease; /* delay on z-index */
   }

and thats it! Hope it helps!! :)

Comment: Thank you!!!! This works great exactly as I wanted, this Is my first use of js and jquery so I feel I done well to get this far, I know about stating the animation before, however, because I didn't know you could start before the action and as the action that's where I fell down. Thanks again!

Comment: awesome! it's really neat - especially for a first piece! Just a note: you aren't 'starting' before the action, you are preparing it. You add the transition in preparation for the change. Basically you want it to know that certain properties will be transitioned before they are actually changed :D